# How to fill an array of unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, c++14, unique-ptr

Is it possible to use `std:fill` to fill an array of `unique_ptr`s? The intention is to have distinct pointers to distinct objects which are initialized with the same parameters.

For example:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> ar[3];
std::fill(ar.begin(), ar.end(), make_unique_for_each_element_somehow<int>(1));
```

Comment: Is `std::array` along with a `std::initializer_list` an option?

Comment: `std::array` is an option but the intent is not to repeat the same filling element `N` times

Comment: That's why I proposed `std::initializer_list` (or simply `{}` initialiization).

Comment: @Light It's amazing. I learn something new every day here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I wasn't aware of it either, but it took all of 10 seconds to hypothesise that there was a `std::fill` overload or sibling function that did this job. Then 10 seconds to confirm via cppreference :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, but this is what [`std::generate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) is for.

Instead of being given a single value that's copied throughout the target range, `std::generate` is given a "generator" function that creates each value as needed.

So, probably, something like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> ar[3];
std::generate(
   std::begin(ar),
   std::end(ar),
   []() { return std::make_unique<int>(1); }
);
```

I haven't tried it, and don't know whether you need to fiddle with it at all in order to avoid problems stemming from non-copyability. Hopefully move semantics are enough.

(Of course, in C++11, you will need [your own `make_unique` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17903225/560648).)

By the way, your `.begin()` and `.end()` were wrong (arrays don't have member functions), so (thanks to a reminder from songyuanyao) I have corrected those.

Comment: @songyuanyao: Yes :)

Comment: @Quentin: OP has tagged the question C++14. She or he or it can always fall back on a homebrew `make_unique` if needed :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit to be fair I added the C++14 tag after Quentin's comment :) seeing as your solution is the most concise but only works in C++14 as written.

Comment: @JeJo: Indeed. Write an answer!

Comment: @JeJo: Please do not post answers as comments thanks

Comment: How to fix this if the size was not available in compile-time? e.g.  contents from a `vector`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72924076/how-to-fill-in-unique-ptr-from-vector-with-run-time-size

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you can do it with `std::fill()` but it is trivial to do with `std::generate()`:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> array[10];
std::generate(std::begin(array), std::end(array),
              []{ return std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(17)); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> ar[3];

size_t i;
for (i = 0; i < elementsof(ar); ++i) {
    ar[i].reset(new int);
}
```