# C++ unique_ptr array of polymorphic type

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following problem. I have unique_ptr to an array of a base class A. Which in pure C++ is no problem to initialize with a pointer to an array of a derived type B. Now with the unique_ptr<A[]> I fail to get this working. I don't see the issue and want to avoid going the custom deleter route. I there something other off with my approach?

```
struct A {
    virtual ~A() {};
};

struct B : public A {
    int min, max;
};

unique_ptr<A[]> a_arr;

// fails
a_arr.reset(new B[2048]);
a_arr = make_unique<B[]>(2048);

// works
A* a_raw_arr = new B[2048];
```

Comment: Your last line may compile but it doesn’t work like you’d want it to. The uniqueptr lines failing to compile are a good thing.

Comment: Why do you use `unique_ptr<A[]> a_arr;` instead of `std::vector<A> a_arr;`? (Or for the sake of this problem, `std::vector<A*> a_arr;` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> a_arr;`)

Comment: _"is no problem to initialize with a pointer to an array of a derived type B"_ — I believe this actually is a problem.

Comment: Ok, I see where I went wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store elements of a derived type in an array of the base tape because they will not fit.  What you can do is to have an array of pointers.

Comment: There is no _array of the base type_ in the OP's case. Only a pointer to an array. I would better write something that one _cannot treat an array of derived objects via a pointer to an array of base objects_.

Comment: @DanielLangr The unique_ptr is templated against `A[]`. I don't see all the finer impact of it, but it definitely does something array-ish. Personally, I'd rather have an array (or vector) of unique_ptr<A>.

Comment: @Jeffrey I agree, I just pointed to the misinterpretation. OP does not store objects of `B` into an array of `A`, there is no array of `A` involved.

Answer (score 1):

@ChristopherYeleighton gave you the reason. The way around is to use an array of unique_ptr as opposed to a unique_pointer to an array.

```
std::unique_ptr<A> a_arr[2048] = {std::make_unique<B>()};
```

Alternatively, a `std::vector` of `unique_ptr<A>` would also work.

The main thing you gain of this is that you are now allowed to have pointers to different derived classes in your `a_arr`.

Comment: Note that your code will initialize only the first element of `a_arr` to `std::make_unique<B>()`. Other elements will be default-initialized. See, e.g., [Initialization of all elements of an array to one default value in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1065774/580083) and [How to fill an array of unique_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41365505/580083).